# Spring Elasticsearch - None of the configured nodes are available

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, jhipster

I am using spring-boot with Elasticsearch. The project was created using jhipster.

pom.xml contains:

```
<parent>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> 
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

and

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In production mode, the following error occurs:

```
AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes :    
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of  
the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}
{localhost/127.0.0.1:9300}]
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: if you run jhipster project with default elasticsearch configuration then be sure that your elasticsearh server version is 1.7 because jhipster java project works with this version.

Comment: in development profile there was such a problem which I couldn't solve yet.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In development profile, JHipster uses an embedded Elasticsearch.

In production profile, it tries by default to connect to a local cluster, so either you don't have installed Elasticsearch on your local machine or you
haven't configured the right URL in `application-prod.yml` to connect to an existing cluster.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I face the same issue check most of the situation on server but not get success.

Comment: More than 4 years later? Sorry, I can't

Comment: It's okay sir, Thanks a lot above solution worked. Actually My service has auto-restart functionality and because of that profile change configuration not applied.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks Gaël Marziou. 
I installed Elasticsearch on my local machine but the problem persist. So, this is my application-prod.yml file.

```
# ===================================================================
# Spring Boot configuration for the "prod" profile.
#
# This configuration overrides the application.yml file.
# ===================================================================

# ===================================================================
# Standard Spring Boot properties.
# Full reference is available at:
# http://docs.spring.io/spring-                    
boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html
# ===================================================================


spring:
    devtools:
        restart:
        enabled: false
    livereload:
        enabled: false
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gestor_6_0?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
    name:
    username: postgres
    password: abcdef
    hikari:
        data-source-properties:
            cachePrepStmts: true
            prepStmtCacheSize: 250
            prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
            useServerPrepStmts: true
jpa:
    database-platform: com.everest.gestor.domain.util.FixedPostgreSQL82Dialect
    database: POSTGRESQL
    show-sql: false
    properties:
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: false
        hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
data:
    elasticsearch:
        cluster-name:
        cluster-nodes: localhost:9300
mail:
    host: localhost
    port: 25
    username:
    password:
thymeleaf:
    cache: true

liquibase:
contexts: prod

server:
port: 8080
compression:
    enabled: true
    mime-types: text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css, application/javascript, application/json
    min-response-size: 1024

# ===================================================================
# JHipster specific properties
# ===================================================================

jhipster:
http:
    cache: # Used by the CachingHttpHeadersFilter
        timeToLiveInDays: 1461
cache: # Hibernate 2nd level cache, used by CacheConfiguration
    timeToLiveSeconds: 3600
    ehcache:
        maxBytesLocalHeap: 256M
security:
    rememberMe:
        # security key (this key should be unique for your application, and kept secret)
        key: 33ec72f5b6d07e227df6bcad7ca844c50a40abb1
mail: # specific JHipster mail property, for standard properties see MailProperties
    from: gestor_6_0@localhost
metrics: # DropWizard Metrics configuration, used by MetricsConfiguration
    jmx.enabled: true
    spark:
        enabled: false
        host: localhost
        port: 9999
    graphite:
        enabled: false
        host: localhost
        port: 2003
        prefix: gestor_6_0
    logs: # Reports Dropwizard metrics in the logs
        enabled: false
        reportFrequency: 60 # in seconds
logging:
    logstash: # Forward logs to logstash over a socket, used by LoggingConfiguration
        enabled: false
        host: localhost
        port: 5000
        queueSize: 512
```

Answer (score 0):

I change my elasticTemplate method in ElasticSearchConfiguration.java and works fine. I just add the follow lines and set my cluster node name to "Gibborim" in Elasticsearch 2.0.

```
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
        .put("client.transport.sniff", true).put("name","Gibborim").put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").put("network.host","127.0.0.1").build();

    client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9300)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run jhipster project with default elasticsearch configuration then be sure that your elasticsearh server version is 1.7 because jhipster java project works with this version(in production profile)

In development profile there was such a problem which I couldn't solve yet